# Moving and fixing array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm so sorry for my English, but anyway:
I have a massive, like "[arg1, "start, of, text, in, quotes", arg2]" from command "somecommand arg1 "start of text in quotes" ". I'm getting splittted by spaces string, but it's incorrect. I want to make everything from quotes as one position in array:

- Given: arg1 "start of text in quotes" arg2
- Before: [arg1, "start, of, text, in, quotes", arg2]
- After: [arg1, "start of text in quotes", arg2]

And it have to work not only with one double quotes.
There's my code:

```
public static String[] fixArguments(String[] arr) {
        String[] rarr = new String[arr.length];
        System.out.println("===========================");
        System.out.println("fixArguments|arr:"+Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println("fixArguments|rarr:"+Arrays.toString(rarr));
        /*for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(i < start) rarr[i] = arr[i];
            else if(i > end) rarr[i] = arr[i-(end-start)];
            else {
                rarr[i] = StringUtils.join(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, start, end), " ");
            }
        }*/

        int start = -1;
        int end = -1;
        int lastnull = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(rarr[i] == null && lastnull == -1) lastnull = i;
            System.out.println("fixArguments|for:"+i+"|start:"+start);
            System.out.println("fixArguments|for:"+i+"|end:"+end);
            System.out.println("fixArguments|for:"+i+"|arr[i]:"+arr[i]);
            if((arr[i].equalsIgnoreCase("\"") || arr[i].startsWith("\"")) && start == -1) start = i;
            else if((arr[i].equalsIgnoreCase("\"") || arr[i].endsWith("\"")) && start != -1) {
                rarr[start] = StringUtils.join(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, start, i+start), " ");
                System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, start, i+start)));
                System.out.println(arr[i]);

                rarr[start] = rarr[start].substring(1, rarr[start].length()-1);
                System.out.println("fixArguments|for:"+i+"|rar[start]"+rarr[start]);
                start = -1;
                end = i;
            } else {
                rarr[start+1] = arr[end+1];
                System.out.println(rarr[start+1]);
                lastnull = -1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("=================================");
        return rarr;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please simplify your question a bit. May be you can mention a sample input and what would be your desired output? So that we can understand the requirement completely.

Comment: So, given an array such as this: `[foo, bar, "foo, bar"]`, you want to get the following array: `[foo, bar, "foobar"]`?

Comment: I think I understand the question... The user is passing the following in the command line: arg1 "somethingA somethingB somethingC" arg2.  @alex-wells wants to get in his end the arg1, arg2 and everything inside the double quotes in another variable, but obviously he is getting the things inside the double quotes split in different positions of the arg. Right?

Comment: vianna77, npinti - yea, u r right, but OldCurmudgeon already asked me and yea) I thank so much all u guys, good luck =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier nowadays to manipulate `List`s than arrays so I have inserted a transform mechanism. You may wish to use the `List` form exclusively.

```
public static List<String> fixArguments(List<String> args) {
    List<String> fixed = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder building = new StringBuilder();
    boolean build = false;
    for (String arg : args) {
        // A " at the start switches to building.
        if (arg.charAt(0) == '\"') {
            build = true;
            building.setLength(0);
        }
        if (build) {
            if (building.length() > 0) {
                building.append(" ");
            }
            building.append(arg);
        } else {
            fixed.add(arg);
        }
        // A " at the end stops the building.
        if (arg.charAt(arg.length() - 1) == '\"') {
            fixed.add(building.toString());
            build = false;
        }
    }
    return fixed;
}

public static String[] fixArguments(String[] arguments) {
    // Roll the array into a List
    List<String> args = Arrays.asList(arguments);
    List<String> fixed = fixArguments(args);
    String[] results = new String[fixed.size()];
    // Roll out the results back into an array.
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        results[i] = fixed.get(i);
    }
    return results;
}

public void test() {
    String[] arguments = new String[]{"One", "\"Two,", "Three,", "Four\"", "Five"};
    String[] fixed = fixArguments(arguments);
    System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.asList(arguments));
    System.out.println("After : " + Arrays.asList(fixed));
}
```

Comment: yea, it works. But: if I enter space - crash (already fixed). But If I enter something like "command arg1 " <-- there is space after quotes and there is too --> "" I get index out of bound over there:
if (arg.charAt(arg.length() - 1) == '\"') {
             fixed.add(building.toString().substring(1, building.length()-1));
             build = false;
         }

Comment: @AlexWells - Yes there are some edge cases I do not deal with - you will need to polish a little. This does not, however, fix the real problem that your command-line splitter is doing a bad job.

Comment: I know that command-line splitter is bad, but it's a compiled game-server core which is used by almost every server (bukkit) and I just cant change anything so I need to do something like this =( But anyway I added some code and now it works even with spaces! 
Thank u and good luck, again =)